# How do you create a Webslice in IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, ie8-webslice, web-slice

How do you create a Webslice in IE8?

Answer (score 4):

- [Internet Explorer 8 Readiness Toolkit - WebSlices](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/readiness/developers-new.aspx#webslices) (Official website)
- [All You Need to Know About IE8 WebSlices - End Users vs. Developers](http://news.softpedia.com/news/All-You-Need-to-Know-about-IE8-WebSlices-End-Users-vs-Developers-80575.shtml)
- [Activities and WebSlices in Internet Explorer 8](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/03/06/activities-and-webslices-in-internet-explorer-8.aspx)
- [Creating Basic WebSlices for IE8](http://blogs.tech-recipes.com/shamanstears/2008/03/13/creating-basic-webslices-for-ie8/)
- [Internet Explorer aka IE 8 home page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/default.aspx) at MSDN
- [Subscribing to Content with Web Slices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc196992(VS.85).aspx) at MSDN

Answer (score 0):

Nice blog regarding Authentication and webslices:

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/web-slice-and-feed-authentication-developer-guidelines)